Why is the printf Output Order Not Respected in a Concurrent Scenario with Piped or Redirected stdout?
We are in a concurrent scenario where we have n concurrent processes. By using a synchronization policy (e.g., using pipes or signals), each process can print using printf("string\n") only if it receives a token from the previous process, ensuring a specific printing order.
When stdout is attached to a terminal (e.g., a console), the expected printing order is respected, meaning processes print in the exact order defined by the synchronization policy. However, when stdout is piped or redirected to a file or another process, the resulting printing order may not be respected, even though the processes still follow the synchronization policy correctly.
We know that printf is buffered by default, meaning it does not immediately write to stdout but instead accumulates output in a buffer before flushing it.
In a concurrent environment, it seems the operating system writes each process's buffer in an order independent of the intended synchronization policy, causing out-of-order prints. This is unexpected given that each process follows the policy correctly.
However, this problem does not occur if one of the following solutions is implemented:

Forcing a flush after each call to printf using fflush(stdout);
Disabling buffering for stdout in each child process using setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);.
Using the system call write(1, "string\n", strlen("string\n")); instead of printf, since write bypasses buffering and directly writes to stdout.

Does anyone know why this happens? What is the operating system's policy regarding this?

Are you asking why output to a file (or more generally, to a non-terminal)  is buffered?

Yes, that’s correct. Why is output to a file, or more generally to a non-terminal (such as when stdout is piped or redirected), buffered by default? What are the major improvements in handling I/O operations efficiently compared to leaving it unbuffered? From my perspective, the buffered output might not be written to the file or pipe in the same order, since the operating system may decide to flush the buffers of each process in an unpredictable order.

Um, what exactly is it you're asking? You already know that output to a terminal is not buffered (actually, it's usually line buffered, but you don't see that if you print full lines) but output to a file is block buffered; and you know the buffers can be flushed with fflush() or the buffering mode changed via setvbuf(). That's the policy part and how to override it.

You also ask in the comment for the "major improvements in handling I/O operations efficiently", which to me seems to answer the question: it's about efficiency. You also mentioned using the system call (write()) instead of the library call (printf()) bypasses the buffering. That's an important point, since it implies the buffering is done in the userland library level, not at the kernel level. (Though I suppose one can argue if the C library is part of the OS or not, but it's not like the low-level OS is forcing you to that buffering.)

Given the above, I'm a bit confused as to why you'd think the result is "unexpected"? You know the system buffers your writes, and that's the result you're seeing, right? The OS (be it the kernel or library) doesn't know about your syncronization policy, and it can't reason about what that should mean regarding the result.


since the operating system may decide to flush the buffers of each process in an unpredictable order.

The operating system is unaware of each process's buffer and cannot make such decisions. The buffers are completely internal to each process's C library (or other runtime library) and the OS has no control of when they are flushed, or whether they exist at all – indeed the entire point of such buffers is that no write syscalls are made to the OS (i.e. the OS is deliberately not made aware of buffered data) until the buffer is flushed.
So if you don't fflush() or setlinebuf(), there is no operating system policy; the order of the prints is approximately the order in which each process fills its buffer to the limit (if they all print multiple lines) or the order in which each process exits (flushing its buffers on exit).
